# How to detect power button event android app

Tags: android

I detect the power button pressed event in android. In the normal app pressed power button then the device screen is OFF, but when creating a system certificate app then the device screen remain ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    // do what you want with the power button
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or Try this

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // do what you want with the power button
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: Try both code but this works only when it is a long press